# Linq Group by With projection into a list

Tags: c#, linq

I'm trying to group by an object and project it into a list in such a way that each element of a list property generates a projected object in this new list.

The source object is is like this:

The source is like:

```
[
  {
    Language: "EN",                                         
    TargetLanguages: [
       "FR",
       "IT",
       "DE"                                        
     ]
  },
  {
    Language: "FR",                                         
    TargetLanguages: [
          "PT",
          "IT",
          "DE"                                        
       ]
  },
  {
     Language: "EN",                                         
     TargetLanguages: [
          "FI",
          "PT"                               
        ]
    }
]
```

I need to group by language and target language
What I have so far is this:

```
var requestsGroupedBySl = nonEuTranslationRequests
                .GroupBy(nonEu => new {
                    nonEu.TranslationSource.Language
                })
                .Select(nonEu => new
                {
                    nonEu.Key.Language,
                    targetLanguages =nonEu.SelectMany(request => request.TargetLanguages)
                })
                .ToList();
```

Which gives me this:

```
Language: "EN",
TargetLanguage: [
    "FR",
    "IT",
    "DE"                                        
]
```

And what I really want is this, one object for each unique language-targetLanguage pair.

```
[
    {
        Language: "EN",                                         
        TargetLanguage: "FR"
    },
        {
        Language: "EN",                                         
        TargetLanguage: "IT"
    },

        {
        Language: "EN",                                         
        TargetLanguage: "DE"
    }

]
```

How can I achieve that?

Comment: FYI you don't need an anonymous type in the `GroupBy` if you're only grouping on one thing.  And for what you want you shouldn't be grouping at all.

Comment: Wouldn't the desired output be what the source is without grouping?

Comment: Could you share the class structure?

Comment: I've added it to the original post.

Answer (score 2):

You should change a bit the logic of the `.Select` over the group:

```
var result = nonEuTranslationRequests
            .GroupBy(i => i.TranslationSource.Language)
            .Select(g => g.SelectMany(r => r.TargetLanguages).Select(i => new {
                g.Key.Language,
                TargetLanguage = i
            })
            .ToList();
```

Also, as you are grouping by a single property there is no need to create an anonymous object to group by.

Comment: @Roberto Jarzembowski - Did this help you solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

You can also use value tuples in @GiladGreen solution instead anonymous objects. Try this:

```
var result = nonEuTranslationRequests
   .GroupBy(x => x.TranslationSource.Language)
   .Select(group => group.Select(item => (Language: item.Key.Language, TargetLanguages: item.TargetLanguages)))
   .ToList();
```

Note that you should use С# 7 and .NET Framework >= 4.7

See more: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.valuetuple?view=netframework-4.7.2